# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(n+4) - \ln(n)$.

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

My initial (incorrect) attempt:

> $\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(n+4) - \ln(n)$ = $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n+4)}{\ln(n)}$
>
> Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(n+4) = \infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(n) = \infty$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n+4)}{\ln(n)}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$; an indeterminate form.
>
> Using L'Hospital's Rule: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n+4)}{\ln(n)}$ becomes $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n+4}}{\frac{1}{n}}$ or $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+4}$.
>
> Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} n = \infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} n+4 = \infty$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+4}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$; also an indeterminate form.
>
> Using L'Hospital's Rule again: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+4}$ becomes $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1}$ or $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1=1$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It must be $$\log(n+4)-\log n=\log\frac{n+4}n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\log1=0$$

Comment: **Formatting tip:** When entering trig functions, notice that adding \ before the functions looks much better 
see `$sin x$` gives $sin x$ whereas `$\sin x$` gives $\sin x$. The same goes in the case of log functions, see 
`$\log x$` and `$\ln x$` give $\log x$ and $\ln x$ and look better, as opposed to `$log x$` and `$ln x$` which 
give $log x$ and $ln x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ln {(n+4)}- \ln {(n)}=\underbrace{\ln {\Bigg(\frac{n+4}{n}\Bigg)}}_{\text{Correct}} \neq \underbrace{\frac{\ln(n+4)}{\ln(n)}}_{\text{What you did}}$$

$$\text{Since}~:\lim_{n \to \infty} \Bigg(\frac{n+4}{n}\Bigg)=1 \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln \Bigg (\frac{n+4}{n}\Bigg)= \ln 1 =0 $$